# c# Math game win counter

Tags: c#, while-loop

So I created a game where player one and player two can play a game where they answer math questions, basically they go one after another for 5 rounds, so if one player answers the question right first they "Win" and if they both answer it right it is a "tie". Kind of a weird way to explain a weird game, but that's not my issue. I already finished the game inside of a class and it is functional and fine, my problem is that I need the players to play 5 games, and for it to tell who won the game the most, ex: "Player 1( or player 2, or draw) has won {0} times!" I have tried a lot of different things, but its all not working. Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{      
   string ID = "";
   bool gOver = false;

   Console.WriteLine("ID 1 ");
   ID = Console.ReadLine();
   MathGame p1 = new MathGame(1, ID);
   Console.WriteLine();
   Console.WriteLine("ID 2");
   ID = Console.ReadLine();
   MathGame p2 = new MathGame(2, ID);
   Console.WriteLine();

   while (!gOver)
   {              
      MathGame.prblm();

      while (!p1.Game() && !p2.Game())                   
         gOver = true;               
   }
}
```

To reiterate; I'd like to make the game loop 5 times and tell me who won the most. I feel like my mistake is simple, make its just where I'm tired. Thanks for any and all help, this website is very helpful.

Comment: just add a `for` loop around the `while` loop, resetting your `gOver` each time

Comment: and if you can already tell who won, put a counter to keep track of each players wins

Comment: Not all too sure how to add a counter to this one, is there a msdn page that I could read about this on?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your game in a for loop, not a while. Then when the while loop (of your game) ends you should check who won and tally it. After the for loop you should have counters to display then.
There are many ways to "tally" but the easiest would be to add a variable for each player and increment when they win.

```
const in GAME_COUNT_TO_PLAY = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < GAME_COUNT_TO_PLAY; i++)
{
      MathGame.prblm();

       while (!p1.Game() && !p2.Game())
       {
           //Keep track of score here, incriment some counter for winner
           //e.g. if(p1.Win) p1Count++;
        }
}
```

After the for loop you can check for who won.

```
if(p1Count > p2Count)
    Display("Player 1 Wins!");
else if(p1Count < p2Count)
    Display("Player 2 Wins!")
else
    Display("Draw!");
```

Comment: I had never thought to use a new variable for the loop, that works so much  better than what I had been previously testing. My code already does check who wins in my class, so all I have to do is in the while loop count who won the most. thanks for your solution, this was very helpful.

Comment: Well actually, this solution is creating an infinite loop, it goes way past 5 rounds.

Comment: added a break; that fixed the loop issue

Comment: Not sure what you have in your "Game" method, but the code provided will not go more than 5. It is likely there is something wrong inside the "Game" method not provided. If you added a "break" then you are NOT going to play 5 games. The for loop is counting the 5 games, while the "Game" code (not posted) should be managing the actual game questions and completing. It is likely you do not even need the inner loop and that is your problem. However, since you did not post the "Game" method I could not be certain of your implementation and mimicked how you originally had it.

Comment: Also your math games likely need to be reinitialized after they complete a game.